# What does the notation max! mean?

Tags: notation

In

> [Koenker, Roger, and Ivan Mizera. "Quasi-concave density estimation."
>   *The Annals of Statistics* (2010): 2998-3027.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4013.pdf)

There is a notation of adding the symbol $!$ after $\max$ and $\min$

Some examples from the paper:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(X_i) = \max_{f}! \hspace{0.5cm} \mbox{ such that } f \mbox{ is a log-concave density.}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) + \int \psi(g(x)) \mbox{dx} = \min_{g \in \mathcal{C}(X)}! \hspace{0.5cm} \mbox{subject to } g \in \mathcal{K}(X)
$$

and one without any constraint:

$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i) + \frac{1}{|\beta|} \int |g(x)|^\beta \mbox{dx} = \min_{g \in C(X)}!
$$

What does that notation mean?

Comment: Could it stand for the objective function? I know German authors like Zeidler also uses that notation

Comment: It seems to be a shorthand for (in your first example) "is to be maximized with respect to $f$ which is constrained to be log-concave".  Sort of like $\text{argmax}$.